# Can Thraustochytrids such as Schizochytrium do photosynthesis?

Tags: algae

I know they belong to the phylum of heterokonts and that they are being heterotrophically grown on an industrial scale but I can't seem to find any reference to them being grown photoautotrophically. People call them marine algae yet there is no mention of photosynthesis.

I did find this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11746-003-0773-2) which says they have several carotenoids so I assume they have those because of their LHC's and photoprotection. It would be great if anyone had some more detailed information (papers) regarding their properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think not.

from Kingdoms and Domains: An Illustrated Guide to the Phyla of Life on Earth By Lynn Margulis, Michael J Chapman. as found on [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=9IWaqAOGyt4C&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=thraustochytrids+R.Golder&source=bl&ots=1FsU4ePi6A&sig=w_A2i1wpcAYu6pk0wwBXuREnL5E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNgMm_kJTVAhXGdD4KHSurANcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=thraustochytrids%20R.Golder&f=false)

You will see there are no chloroplasts depicted.  These are eukaryotes and so to do photosynthesis they would need chloroplasts which should be evident.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a more definitive answer since photosynthesis jumps in and out of the heterokont lineage but your information is a lot better than what I found. Thanks!